# Swift filtering firebase data by child node

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter my firebase data within the table view to group items that have the same category (child value) after each other. Currently, it's not returning the values based on the child value. I think it's being done in random order.

Here is my code:

**How I'm attempting to filter the data:**

```
self.items.append(item)

  self.items.sort(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
  return item1.category.compare(item2.category) == .orderedSame
  })

 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

**Model:**

```
struct Item {

var id: String?

var user: User
var fromId: String?
let item: String
let category: String
let creationDate: Date

init(user: User, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.user = user
    self.item = dictionary["item"] as? String ?? ""
    self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String ?? ""
    self.category = dictionary["category"] as? String ?? ""

    let secondsFrom1970 = dictionary["creationDate"] as? Double ?? 0
    self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
}
}
```

**Fetch function:**

```
    fileprivate func fetchListItems() {
    self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let listId = list?.id else { return }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("lists").child(listId).child("list-items")
    ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let itemId = snapshot.key

        let itemRef = Database.database().reference().child("items").child(itemId)
        itemRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let itemId = snapshot.key

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            guard let uid = dictionary["fromId"] as? String else { return }

            Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid, completion: { (user) in

                var item = Item(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

                item.id = snapshot.key

                self.items.append(item)

                    self.items.sort(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
                        return item1.category.compare(item2.category) == .orderedSame
                    })

                self.tableView.reloadData()
                ref.keepSynced(true)
            })
        })
    }

}
```

**Database:**

[image: Database picture]

Comment: None of the code you shared is reading from Firebase, so it's hard to say why that part doesn't work.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Fixed

Comment: all you want to try is to get data related to specific user and by Category.?

Comment: Yes, trying to fetch the data by Category and show it as so. For example show all the Dairy items after one another then the Bread & Bakery items. Eventually, I will add table view headers between them. @AtifAbbAsi

Comment: what about this node structure like items->userId->RandomKey->item .?
and then search 
Database.database().reference().child("items").child(userId).orderBy("category").equals(category).? @CodyHost

Comment: Are you asking how to read in all of child nodes in the items node, with a [query ordered by child](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sort_data) of category? (that link is a hint btw)